# Smartgit can not clone: Please set the VM property sshClient.scriptPath to directory without spaces

Tags: git, windows-8, smartgit

64bit Windows 8
Smartgit/Hg 5.0.8

I get this error when trying to clone to directory repository from bitbucket:

```
Please set the VM Property sshClient.scriptPath to a directory without spaces in its path and restart SmartGit/Hg!
```

Where should i set that path? and what should be the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across the same problem on a Windows 7 machine at work. Create a temp directory with no spaces in the path like

> C:\git\tmp

And then open up %AppData%\syntevo\SmartGit\ and find your **smartgit.properties** file. Add the following property

> java.io.tmpdir=c:\git\tmp

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good solution, but I don't use that version anymore.. Works fine now with windows 8.1 and smartgit v6

Comment: I had the same problem with smartgit v6, but glad your problem resolved itself.